# Handler not updating GUI

Tags: java

When I receive SOS I want to be hable to cancel the sms sending if I click a button within a time.

The time is configured on the GUI and should be `int delay = Integer.parseInt(cancelTime.getText().toString())*1000;` for example 10x1000 = 10 seconds to click the button.

```
if(data.equals("SOS\r\n")) {

        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        int delay = Integer.parseInt(cancelTime.getText().toString())*1000;

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                double elapsedTime = ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime)/1000);
                alertButton.setText("CANCEL THE SOS: " + elapsedTime);
                alertButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));

                alertButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        wasCanceled = true;
                    }
                });

                if(!wasCanceled)
                { 
                   //SEND SMS
                }
                else if(wasCanceled)
                {
                    alertButton.setText("CANCELED!!");
                    alertButton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));
                }
            }
        }, delay);
    }
    }
```

My problem is that the GUI is not updating. It only updates when I click the button.

```
            alertButton.setText("CANCEL THE SOS: " + elapsedTime);
            alertButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
```

Also I wanted the time to decrement like 10...9... until 0. Atm is incrementing.

Comment: I think your code is running AFTER the waiting delay, not before...

Comment: what do you advice me to do then? @UsagiMiyamoto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
if ("SOS\r\n".equals(data))
{
  final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  final Handler handler = new Handler();
  final int delay = Integer.parseInt(cancelTime.getText()) * 1000;
  final long endTime = startTime + delay;
  wasCanceled = false;
  alertButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
  {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
      wasCanceled = true;
    }
  });
  final Runnable r = new Runnable()
  {
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
      final double remainingTime = (endTime - System.currentTimeMillis()) / 1000d;
      alertButton.setText("CANCEL THE SOS: " + elapsedTime);
      alertButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
      if(wasCanceled)
      {
        alertButton.setText("CANCELED!!");
        alertButton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));
        return;
      }
      else if(remainingTime < 0)
      { 
        // SEND SMS
        return;
      }
      handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
    }
  };        
  handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
}
```

Since it is re`postDelayed()` itself after doing some stuff, you might want to lower the inner delay from `1000` to `800` or something like that...